# OpenMP Dynamic For Loop Chunk Remainders

Tags: for-loop, openmp

When specifying a chunk size for a for loop in OpenMP, if there is a remainder, is it handled by the compiler? For example, if I am iterating through 13 points, with chunk size 4 and 3 threads, assuming that all threads are used, will one of them be given a 5th point, or do I need to specify this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes OpenMP handles that for you. You don't have to specify anything.

I assume you talk about static scheduling here since for dynamic scheduling it seems rather evident.

For instance from [Intel doc](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-loop-scheduling) static scheduling

> Divide the loop into equal-sized chunks **or as equal as possible in the
>   case where the number of loop iterations is not evenly divisible by
>   the number of threads multiplied by the chunk size.**

The remaining chunks are divided depending on the implementation.

If you want more details according to [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w1x7937.aspx)

> For a team of p threads, let ceiling(n/p) be the integer q, which
>   satisfies n = p*q - r with 0 <= r < p. One implementation of the
>   static schedule for this example would assign q iterations to the
>   first p–1 threads, and q-r iterations to the last thread. Another
>   acceptable implementation would assign q iterations to the first p-r
>   threads, and q-1 iterations to the remaining r threads. This
>   illustrates why a program should not rely on the details of a
>   particular implementation.